# How to compute the argmin over vectors?

Tags: vector-analysis

Can I just differentiate to find the argmin if I'm looking for a vector and if yes which differentiation is used for such questions as below?  $f$ is differentiable.
$v_0 = argmin_{v\in \mathbb{R^n}} f(v)$
And further can anyone give me a source with useful differentiation rules if I have vectors, e.g. how to differentiate $\|v-x\|_2^2.$

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not too clear. So I make some assumptions.

Yes, you can use `ArgMin` to get the argument of the minimum.

Concerning your vectors, I assume that one vector `b` is a given constant and the other `a`  is a position vector, With this, the derivatives are:

```
a = {x, y};
b = {x0, y0};
D[(a - b).(a - b), x]
(* 2 (x - x0 *)

D[(a - b).(a - b), y]
(* 2 (y - y0) *)
```